# How to render another component's scoped slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

## Minimal Complete Verifiable Example

[This CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wave-vq7ri?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the MCVE.

## Problem Description

To describe my problem briefly, I have the following structure of renderless components (all use scoped slots and only render the first item of those):

- `FragmentA` that are meant to be used with `FragmentB`s inside them
- `FragmentB` that are meant to be used with `FragmentC`s inside them
- `FragmentC` that will render its scoped slot

The problem lies in the fact that on occasion, depending on some input, `FragmentC` should render a `FragmentB` instead.

In order to avoid to repeat the `FragmentB` part in the userland template, I'd like to be able to render `FragmentB`'s scoped slot inside `FragmentC` using input data from `FragmentC`.

This sort of "recursion" is ensured to have a base case that renders `FragmentC`'s own slot.

## What I've tried so far

I have tried to get access to the slot directly using the provide/inject API, how the scoped itself is accessed *might* not be the problem, I *believe* it comes from how I try to render it.

#### Render as only child

```js
// FragmentC.vue
{
  inject: ["$fragB"],
  components: { FragmentB },
  render(h){
    return /*some condition*/
    ? this.$scopedSlots.default(/* render own scoped slot */)[0]
    : h(
      FragmentB,
      {},
      this.$fragB.$scopedSlots.default(/* render FragmentB scoped slot */)[0]
    );
  }
}
```

This will result, in the recursively rendered `FragmentB`, in `this.$scopedSlots.default` not being a function.

#### Render as an array of children

```js
// FragmentC.vue
{
  inject: ["$fragB"],
  components: { FragmentB },
    return /*some condition*/
    ? this.$scopedSlots.default(/* render own scoped slot */)[0]
    : [h(
      FragmentB,
      {},
      this.$fragB.$scopedSlots.default(/* render FragmentB scoped slot */)[0]
    )];
}
```

This will cause an infinite recursion.

## The concrete question in one sentence

How does one go about programatically rendering another component's scoped slot inside of another component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and a bit of fiddling with the code, I found that the following solution allowed to render properly :

```
// FragmentC.vue
{
  inject: ["$fragB"],
  components: { FragmentB },
  render(h){
    return /*some condition*/
    ? this.$scopedSlots.default(/* render own scoped slot */)[0]
    : h(
      FragmentB,
      {
          props: {/*fragB props*/},
          scopedSlots: {
              default: this.$fragB.$scopedSlots.default(/* render FragmentB scoped slot */)[0],
          }
      },
      [
          this.$fragB.$scopedSlots.default(/* render FragmentB scoped slot */)[0],
      ]
    );
  }
}
```